# How to create certificate for SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer()?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, x509certificate

I’m trying to write a server application that uses SSL to communicate. After accepting a connection, I believe I have to call `SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer`. However, this expects a certificate and I do not understand how to create one.

I followed the advice given in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214396):

> I ran the following to create a server.pfx file:
>
> ```
> makecert.exe -r -pe -n "CN=localhost" -sky exchange -sv server.pvk
> server.cer pvk2pfx -pvk server.pvk -spc server.cer -pfx server.pfx
> ```
>
> Then I loaded it in code with:
>
> ```
> certificate = new X509Certificate2("server.pfx", "password");
> ```

However, I did that exactly, and I get a `CryptographicException` saying “The specified network password is not correct.”, which is patently false because I used the password `x`, which is very hard to mistype. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

[How to: Create Your Own Test Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx)